# Need to distinguish gridview after cellclick for each row

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, datagridview

i need to distinguish a datagridview on c# for each row..
i have a "Exam" field on database with default data is "No", so if the Exam field change to "Yes", so the data gridview with a username that contain Exam field "Yes" the datagridview must change the command column default text from "Participate" to "Finished"..
this, example data gridview, the actions columns is a command column

```
Username   Name    Actions 
Habib123   Habib   Participate
Habib12    Wisnu   Participate
Habib12    Pratama Participate
```

so if I click Participate on "Habib12" Username the Exam field on database is automatically change to "Yes" and the datagridview should be like this..

```
Username   Name    Actions 
Habib123   Habib   Participate
Habib12    Wisnu   Finished
Habib12    Pratama Participate
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: If you use a DataTable as the DataSource of the DataGridView, you should implement the CellClick event, and in this event update the DataRow corresponding to the current DataGridViewRow.

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!